# WSO2 - MSSQL causes error for commits

Tags: api, database-connection, wso2

When configuring WSO2 API Manager version 1.5.0 to use SQL Server as my database the instructions at:
http://docs.wso2.org/display/AM150/Setting+up+with+MS+SQL

For step 1 for Setup Configuration File, they tell you to update the master-datasources.xml file to match their example.

After updating and starting the API Manager, I got the following error in the logs:
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO} -  Failed to rollback getting user ratings  {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO}
java.sql.SQLException: commit() should not be called while in auto-commit mode.

Answer (score 3):

We tried a couple of things.  First we disabled auto-commit on our SQL Server (2008r2).

That did not help and the error continued.  After researching jdbc connections at: http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html

I discovered that a setting for:

```
        <defaultAutoCommit>false</defaultAutoCommit>
```

was needed for each database definition in master-datasources.xml
For example:

```
<datasource>
    <name>WSO2_CARBON_DB</name>
    <description>The datasource used for registry and user manager</description>
    <jndiConfig>
        <name>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</name>
    </jndiConfig>
    <definition type="RDBMS">
        <configuration>
            <defaultAutoCommit>false</defaultAutoCommit>
            <url>jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://server:port/db_name</url>
      <username>user</username>
            <password>pwd</password>
            <driverClassName>net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
            <maxActive>50</maxActive>
            <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
            <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
            <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
            <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
        </configuration>
    </definition>
</datasource>
```

The documentation from WSO2 does not reference this setting that I have found.  It 'might' set it correctly when using the ../carbon admin site for your product.

Comment: Yes. Even though WSO2 documentation does not mention it, if you are using the MSSQL with WSO2 API Manager, it is a must to use this parameter or equivalent in the connection url to avoid this issue.